# Hadoop: How to maintain counter for datanode method execution?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

***I would like to know how to maintain a count for the number of times a method has been executed on a particular datanode within a MapReduce Job.***

Unfortunately with the code I have developed so far, I am producing very unfavourable results. The count variable being transmitted using the 'makeRequest' method behaves very irrationally (and produces a repeating pattern). The results can be viewed here: [image: results]

The 'count' should only ever increase for any given MapReduce Job. I feel as though it is important to note that the primary input file I am using is simply the numbers: 0 - 750,000 (one number per line). The desired final result should have a count of 750,000 being reported to the server.

Just to provide a little bit of background: I am currently developing a Prime-Numbers MapReduce program which aims to periodically (based on a timer) relays information in terms of the 'number' of numbers processed to a server. The server is hosted on the master node and aims to display the results of the job in real time.

Please excuse me if I've made any blatant mistakes in my understanding of the Hadoop Framework, unfortunately I'm still quite new to it and still learning.

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask; 

/** Hadoop MapReduce program to compute the prime numbers based on a given range provided within the input file. */

public final class Primes {

public static int counter = 0; 
public static boolean created = false;

/**
 * Defines Job Configuration
 */
public final static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
    final Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    conf.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://master:9000");
    conf.set("mapreduce.jobtracker.address", "master:5431");
    conf.set("mapreduce.framework.name", "yarn");
    conf.set("yarn.resourcemanager.address", "master:8050");
    final Job job = new Job(conf, "Primes");
    job.setJarByClass(Primes.class);

    job.setOutputKeyClass(NullWritable.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    job.setMapperClass(PrimesMap.class);

    job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
    job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

    job.waitForCompletion(true);
}

/**
 * Creates a timer which processes a GET request to the
 * hosted server, repeating every five seconds.
 */
public final static void createRequestTimer(){
    Timer timer = new Timer(); 
    TimerTask request = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run(){ makeRequest(counter);}
    };

    int delay = 3000; 
    int period = 5000;
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(request, delay, period); 
}

public static final class PrimesMap extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, NullWritable, IntWritable> {
    final NullWritable nw = NullWritable.get(); 
    public final void map(final LongWritable key, final Text value, final Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        final int number = Integer.parseInt(value.toString());

        /**
         * Creates a timer the first time this method is executed. Ensures that only one
         * timer will be maintained.
         */
        if(created == false){
            createRequestTimer(); 
            created = true; 
        }

        /**
         * Checks to see if the number is in fact prime
         */
        if(isPrime(number)) {
            context.write(nw, new IntWritable(number));
        }

    }
}

/**
 * Basic primality test
 */
private static final boolean isPrime(final int number) {
    //Function should be performed on all numbers, and therefore
    //Can be incremented within this function (as the first step)
    counter++;
    if(number <= 1){
        return false; 
    }

    if(number == 2) {
        return true; 
    }

    if(number % 2 == 0){
        return false; 
    }

    for(int i = 3; i <= Math.sqrt(number) + 1; i = i + 2){
        if(number % i == 0){
            return false; 
        }
    }
    return true;
}

/**
 * Based on the counter parameter, a get request will be made to the
 * server. This method is effectively used to relay the number of numbers
 * that have been processed by this particular node to the server (which 
 * then goes on to display results in real time). 
 */
private static void makeRequest(int counter){
    String url = "http://192.168.1.2:5000/add/1/" + counter ;

    try {
        String IP = InetAddress.getLocalHost().toString();
        if(IP.contains("192.168.1.3")){
            url = "http://192.168.1.2:5000/add/1/" + counter; 
        }
        else if(IP.contains("192.168.1.4")){
            url = "http://192.168.1.2:5000/add/2/" + counter;
        }
        else if(IP.contains("192.168.1.5")){
            url = "http://192.168.1.2:5000/add/3/" + counter;
        }
        else if(IP.contains("192.168.1.6")){
            url = "http://192.168.1.2:5000/add/4/" + counter;
        }
        else if(IP.contains("192.168.1.7")){
            url = "http://192.168.1.2:5000/add/5/" + counter;
        }
        else if(IP.contains("192.168.1.8")){
            url = "http://192.168.1.2:5000/add/6/" + counter;
        }
        else if(IP.contains("192.168.1.9")){
            url = "http://192.168.1.2:5000/add/7/" + counter;
        }
        else if(IP.contains("192.168.1.10")){
            url = "http://192.168.1.2:5000/add/8/" + counter;
        }

        URL myurl = new URL(url);         
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) myurl.openConnection();            
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        con.getInputStream(); 
        con.disconnect();
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

The current results show that the "count" variable being represented increases and decreases in value (which is incorrect).

The desired results for the job are such that the value following "GET /add/1/" is never decreasing, and only increases over the course of the MapReduce Job (as many times as the 'isPrime()' method is called). If I could please get some assistance, it would be really-really appreciated! :)

Once again, to reiterate, I would like to know: ***How I am able to count the number of times each datanode executes a particular method within the Hadoop framework***

The error within the code provided lies solely within the 'counter', and how it is incremented throughout the 'mapper' and 'isPrime' functions. I am unsure as to why the 'counter' variable decreases throughout the course of the program.

Comment: Please note that the 'add' is a little misleading: the idea is to 'set' the value of the 'node' (the number which follows the '/add/') to the value that follow's the node. E.g. '/add/1/321' represents that I would like to 'set' the value of data-node-1 to 321.

Comment: can you provide the log as it first starts up

Answer (score 0):

It has 3 threads.
if you want your update interval to be 5 seconds that is fine .
if these changes are possible it's what i'd look into.
on the aggregator side. the server that accepts the /add/1.... have it start at 0 and add the value sent.
worker side. have it reset the value every time it sends

looking at log statements from the early part of the run may show what is happening better.